# How can I install M4 on Linux, avoiding the dependency loop with Automake and Autoconf?

Tags: compiling, autoconf, m4

I am trying to install GNU M4 on my Chromebook using the 1.4.17 tarball, but when I run `./configure` and then`make` I get an error related to `aclocal`, which is apparently part of the GNU Automake package. The exact error I get is

```
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.14' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
```

I know the first part is only a warning, but the name indicates that the error is related.

I also tried to create an empty file for `aclocal.m4`, and I get a different message: a warning about `automake-1.14` missing and `make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1`

Unfortunately, according to the [official page](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/), Automake requires Autoconf, which in turn [requires M4](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/). What can I do to install M4 and avoid this problem?

Comment: isn't there a m4 package in your linux distro?

Comment: If there was, I wouldn't have this problem. The built in Chromebook operating system has the bare minimum of useful packages, and it does not include any development packages.

Comment: since this is SUSE Linux, aren't there packages that will run on Chromebook?

Comment: I don't know why you say it is SUSE Linux. As far as I can tell, Chrome OS is a heavily modified distribution of Gentoo, which I have no other experience in.

Comment: I installed `Cr_OS_Linux.i686-2.4.1290.iso` and it is Open SUSE. But I've heard also Google switched from Ubuntu to Gentoo.

Comment: does your distro include a package manager, and is there an _autotools_ or _autoconf_ or _automake_ package available via said package manager?

Comment: Do you have perl installed?  I can't reproduce the error you get.  Try downloading the latest tarball; extracting it and just running `./configure; sudo make install` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

The configure file in `m4` and subsequent `make` requires neither m4 nor aclocal, unless one of the files it mentioned has changed, which probably isn't the case.

So the likely cause is (I had this last week) a timestamp problem.

Did you copy the extracted archive into a newer directory? Is the system clock correct?

I built m4 (same version) on my system with aclocal and m4 removed, but if `acinclude.m4` and `configure.ac` were older (`touch --date="last friday" configure.ac`) it returns the same error.

Remove the directory, re-unpack (maybe with tar's `-m` option) and try again.